# receiving weird packages that wireshark cant see in my c++ game

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am currently working on a game that uses a main loop to draw items. Before entering the main loop, I create a thread to receive packets using a low-level packet receiver function. However, when I run my code, I notice that my program receives strange packets with random IP addresses like "237.0.0.0", "45.0.0.0", and "185.0.0.0". These IP addresses change every time I restart the program.

Here is the code for the packet receiver function:

```
//thread creation in main function:
this->receive_thead = std::thread(&OGame::packet_receiver, this);


void OGame::packet_receiver() {
    while (1) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(packet_mutex);
        Packet rec = this->network.Receive();
        if (rec.type == -1)
            continue;
        printf("Received actual packet!\n");
    }
}

Packet AgiborNet::Receive()
{
    Packet packet{ 0 };
    char rec_buffer[sizeof(packet) + 13];
    struct sockaddr_in sender_addr;
    int sender_addr_size = sizeof(sender_addr);
    int recv_size = recvfrom(this->receive_socket, rec_buffer, sizeof(rec_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sender_addr, &sender_addr_size);
    if (sender_addr.sin_addr.s_addr == this->send_ip.sin_addr.s_addr) {
        Packet empty_packet = { 0 };
        empty_packet.type = -1;
        return empty_packet;
    }
    std::cout << inet_ntoa(sender_addr.sin_addr) << ": " << rec_buffer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Packet contents: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < recv_size; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(rec_buffer[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::dec << std::endl;

    return packet;
}
```

I also noticed that Wireshark does not detect these packets. Additionally, when I send at least one packet, my program stops receiving these strange packets. For context, I am listening and waiting for broadcast packets that are on a specific port.

Can someone please help me understand why my program is receiving these strange packets with random IP addresses, and why Wireshark does not detect them? Thank you.

Comment: You should check the return value of `recvfrom`. It may sometimes return without or a partial packet. See the man page.

Comment: @user9609349 I agree with EmanualP. You are not checking `recvfrom()` for failure before using the data it returns, so you are likely acting on garbage at times.

Comment: What kind of socket are you opening? What is the `socket()` call?

Comment: Packets, not packages, right?

Comment: No,, not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as some of you said in the comment the problem was I wasn't checking the return value of recvfrom.